# Incremental crawling settings for new documents in Search

Tags: 2010, search, enterprise-search, crawling

This question about sharepoint 2010 enterprise search.

-- there is incremental crawling running for a content source ,this has one record center web application.

--in this web application daily 5000 documents are saved by users through scan service that we built.

- now we configured incremental crawling schedule to every 20 Min.

Question:
if i not configured incremental crawling this frequent users unable to search new documents using document id .
 so here what is the incremental crawling doing ?
here how can i configure content source without configuring incremental crawling every 20 Min to search for new documents?

Comment: I believe the Document ID service is a timer job. Have you looked at increasing the frequency of this job in conjunction with the incremental schedule?

Answer (score 1):

**Incremental crawl covers the following scenarios,** where SharePoint index files will be updated and search results will affected without the need to perform full crawl:

1. Adding new document to document library or new item to list Edit
   current document content Delete document (incremental crawl will
   detect the deletion and removes it from the index and from search
   results).
2. Changing Item permissions
3. Document properties (columns)

Remaks: Befor Configure incremental Crawl Do Full Crawl for your Source.

Answer (score 0):

Document ID is independent service from the search. You will not be able to search by document ID until after the document has been crawled and indexed.

There is no out of the box solution to push item to index (on SP2010 Fast there is one utility called docpush but this is just for testing not for production environments).

In short to see items via search you need to crawl and index. If contents is updated regularly you need to crawl more often to have fresh index.